# Neo4j paths with only specific types of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph containing many paths and I want to return these paths seperatly
Given the following graph:

```
           B 
         /    \
 A   -  C  -   D
  \____________/
```

and all links are directed, so we have an edge from A->C, A->D, C->D, C->B, B->D.
I would like to get A-C-D, A-C-B-D and A-D as seperate results. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use [variable-length pattern matching](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength).

Assuming at the moment that the nodes are of type :MyNode, and that we're using the property `name` for the node name, and that there's an index on :MyNode(name) for fast lookup:

```
MATCH p = (:MyNode{name:'A'})-[*]->(end)
WHERE NOT exists((end)-->())
RETURN p
```

The WHERE ensures you're only getting paths to an end node that has no outgoing relationships.

If you only want the nodes of the path back instead of the full path, use `RETURN nodes(p)` instead.